# retrieve the value of selected check boxes in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a list of check boxes. in each one I am storing the ID of a user

```
<input type="checkbox" name="student_ids[]" value="{{student.id}}">
```

once the form is submitted, I want to get the list of all the Ids in checkboxes that were selected

Comment: Did you already try `$this->getRequest()->request->get('student_ids')`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

$this->getRequest()->request->get('student_ids')

Only checked text boxes will be included in the array student_ids[];

Comment: instead of using `$this->getRequest()` your controller already has the request just pass it as an argument to your action ( `public function indexAction(Request $request) {}`